# mod_rewrite for IE6 to static page on webserver

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Our new website does not work in IE6 and honestly we wont make it work as its <1% of our traffic. I want to serve up a page that lives on the webserver that will be served up when a user comes to the site in IE6. What would be the best way to achieve this? It would be great if someone can provide a code snippet also.

I was able to get the redirect working by using this:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\ 6
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /general/notsupported.html [L,R]

However, i wanted to also mask the url so if someone comes in on www.example.com/uri/querystring it will stay there but serve up a page saying "Sorry" ie6 is not supported.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} whatever_the_ie6_user_agent_string_is
RewriteRule .* /path/to/your/static/page [R]
```

Comment: how do i mask the url to stay at whatever the incoming url was?

Comment: Just get rid of the `[R]` bit.